# atom beautify plugin break function arguments

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, code-formatting

I'm a newer of atom.

I have install the plugin `atom-beautify` to format my js, css and html.

But for the format of js, I have some question, if I call a function with more than one argument. it will break the argument.

```
// before format
me.addMessage(n.message, n.pmid, function(message){
    console.log(message);
});

// after format
me.addMessage(n.message,
            n.pmid,
            function(
              message) {
              console.log(message);
            });
```

The config is very complex with my low english.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: may be raise an issue here. - https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues

Answer (score 0):

In my case this seemed to be caused by the option `Break chained methods`